# IOS app crash with "bug_type":"179"

Tags: ios, debugging, crash, testflight

My IOS app distributed via testflight crashes randomly
but no crash reports generated with my app name.
the only thing I have is a log- session generated at the same time

```
{"share_with_app_devs":false,"bug_type":"179","os_version":"iPhone OS    11.3.1 (15E302)"}
{
  "scheduled" : true,
  "machine_config" : "iPad6,11",
  "log_version" : 2,
  "region_format" : "US",
   "os_version" : "iPhone OS 11.3.1 (15E302)",
  "language" : "en-IE",
 "sessions_data" : [
{
  "app_arch" : "arm-64bit",
  "app_build_version" : "13",
  "app_version" : "0.1",
 "app_adamid" :12456,
 "app_sessionreporter_key" : ""
 "app_storefront" : 143339,
  "app_bundleid" : "my.bundle.id",
  "app_events" : [
    {
      "date" : "2018-05-25T09:24:15+0100",
      "state" : "foregroundRunning",
      "type" : "app_session",
      "duration" : 3
    },
    {
      "date" : "2018-05-25T09:24:45+0100",
      "state" : "foregroundRunning",
      "type" : "app_session",
      "duration" : 111
    },

 ],
  "app_is_beta" : true,
  "slice_uuid" : "7654321-QUSTU-MNOP-HIJKL-XXXXXX",
   "app_cohort" :     "2|date=1527152400000&sf=143449&tid=h7J8JH3G6G6G6G6Y6T6XXXXXXXXX&ttype=i"
 }
  ],
   "log_timestamp" : "2018-05-25T11:56:50+0100"
 }
```

Any leads to fix this issue

Comment: Please - what did you find?

Comment: Any update on this?